# Comparing a string[index] to another string

Tags: c#

I am in the process of learning C# and I'm building a hangman game from scratch as one of my first projects.

Everything works except for the part that replaces the dashes of the hidden word with the correctly guessed letters.

For example: ----- becomes G-EA- after you guess G, E, and A.

I have a for loop that logically seems like it'd do the job except I can't use the == operator for strings or chars.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= answer.Length; i++) //answer is a string "theword"
            {
                if (answer[i] == passMe) //passMe is "A" for example
                {
                    hiddenWord = hiddenWord.Remove(i, 1);
                    hiddenWord = hiddenWord.Insert(i, passMe);
                }
            }
```

I've scoured the net trying to find a good solution.  Most recommend using Regex or other commands I haven't learned yet and therefore don't fully understand how to implement.

I've tried converting both to char format in the hope that it would fix it, but no luck so far. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where do you define `passMe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `passMe` is a string of only one char then

```
if (answer[i] == passMe[0])
```

In this way you compare the character at i-th position with the character at the first position of your user input

There is also a serious error in your code. 
Your loop goes off by one, change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
```

The arrays in NET start at index zero and, the max index value possible, is always one less than the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

answer[i] refers to a character and passMe is a single character string. (not a character)

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= answer.Length; i++) //answer is a string "theword"
            {
                if (answer[i] == passMe[0]) //passMe is "A" for example
                {
                    hiddenWord = hiddenWord.Remove(i, 1);
                    hiddenWord = hiddenWord.Insert(i, passMe);
                }
            }
```

you need to compare a character with a character.